# How do I evaluate $\int_{0}^{2} \frac{dx}{x + 4 - x^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

The question is from Stewart calculus
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{2} \frac{dx}{x + 4 - x^2} &= \int_{0}^{2} \frac{dx}{-(x^2 - x - 4)} \\
&= -\int_{0}^{2} \frac{dx}{x^2 - x - 4} \\
&= -\int_{0}^{2} \frac{dx}{x^2 - 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot x - 4} \\
&= -\int_{0}^{2} \frac{dx}{(x - \frac{1}{2})^2 - \frac{1}{4} - 4} \\
&= -\int_{0}^{2} \frac{dx}{(x - \frac{1}{2})^2 - \frac{17}{4}}
\end{align*}

Am I on right way or **any method to solve the original integral like trig substitution or any...?**

Comment: You can also use [partial fractions on](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=partial+fractions+1%2F%281%2F4+%281+%2B+sqrt%2817%29+-+2+x%29+%28-1+%2B+sqrt%2817%29+%2B+2+x%29%29) the integrand and integrate with the logarithm

Comment: Please avoid subject lines that are made up entirely of MathJax codes; they break some navigation shortcuts.

Comment: What does that mean I didn't understand

Comment: @ТymaGaidash٠ any other short method to solve?

Comment: @Martin, What Arturo Magidin means is that the title of your post should contain words as well as Maths code. Something like "How do I evaluate [mathjax stuff]" is ok.

Comment: Ok now I understand it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method can be pushed through further!

From:

$$-\int_{0}^{2} \frac{dx}{(x - \frac{1}{2})^2 - \frac{17}{4}}$$

Let $u = x - \frac{1}{2}$ so that $du = dx$.

This [**transforms**](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/awnm9euj2c) your integral into:

$$-\int_{-0.5}^{1.5} \frac{du}{u^2 - \frac{17}{4}}$$

This now fits the familiar or unfamiliar rule:

$$\int \frac{dx}{x^2 - a^2} = - \frac{\tanh(\frac{x}{a})}{a} + C$$

Comment: ... Partial fractions is probably a better answer here, but it might be worth working this version out, too! If you haven't seen "tanh" before, it is the **hyperbolic tangent**.

Comment: @Martin Enjoy!!

Answer (score 2):

Do a $u$-sub $u = x-1/2$.  Then, the integral becomes
$$-\int_{-1/2}^{3/2}\frac{du}{u^2-17/4}.$$Partial fractions is much easier for this version.

Comment: Similar answer similar comment! Just gotta decide where to go next: partial fractions or tanh...

Answer (score 1):

Let:$x_1,x_2$ solution equation $x^2-x-4=0$
then : $4+x-x^2=-(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$
and therfore:
$$\frac{1}{4+x-x^2}=(x_2-x_1)\left({\frac{1}{x-x_1}-\frac{1}{x-x_2}}\right)$$

And therfore :
$$\int^2_0 \frac{dx}{4+x-x^2}=(x_2-x_1)\int^2_0 \left({\frac{1}{x-x_1}-\frac{1}{x-x_2}}\right) \\ = (x_2-x_1)\left({\ln\left({\frac{x-x_1}{x-x_2}}\right)}\right)^2_0=(x_2-x_1)\ln\left({\frac{2-x_1}{2-x_2}}\right)- (x_2-x_1)\ln\left({\frac{x_1}{x_2}}\right)$$

Comment: Solution the equation :$4+x-x^2=0$